# generate makefiles automatically greyed out - eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, makefile, eclipse-cdt

I've noticed when going into the properties of my project, then into `C/C++ Build`, that the `Generate Makefiles Automatically` checkbox is *greyed out* and I can't disable it. This is my first time using **Eclipse**, and so I'm used to just creating my own - and for some reason I can't find a way to disable it.

[image: panel]

All help is appreciated.

Comment: If you want to write your own make files for whatever reason then you should create a make file project instead of managed project.

Answer (score 0):

As **@VTT** pointed out, this has to do with the type of project you choose in the new project wizard.

It's also worth pointing out that in newer versions of Eclipse CDT, the new project wizard is fairly confusing. The `Makefile Project` option on the wizard's first page, whose description is marked as `(Experimental)`, really is experimental and in my experience buggy. I recommend the old-style makefile project, which, confusingly, is created by chosing `C++ Managed Build` on the first page, and *then* `Makefile project` on the second page.